# Setting X-XSS-Protection response headers in Apex has no effect

Tags: apex, xss, header

I created a new Apex class:

public with sharing class PWSHttpHeadersController {

```
public PWSHttpHeadersController(){
    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('X-XSS-Protection','1; mode=block');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=3600; includeSubDomains');
}
public PWSHttpHeadersController(cms.CoreController coreController){
    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('X-XSS-Protection','1; mode=block');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=3600; includeSubDomains');
}
```

}

Once deployed to my sandbox I can see that the Strict Transport Security header in effect but not the XSS protection header.

Have tried setting it to 1 instead of 1:mode=block but that has no effect.

Is this something i am doing wrong?  Or does Salesforce not implement this header in the response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders() returns the **request** headers, which should be read only at this point.

As far as I can see there is no way to set **response** headers.